# Linux to Windows remote desktop - is \\tsclient visible for other computers

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I'm often connecting from my linux computer at home to windows 7 computer at work. I'm using freerdp and remmina. I'm also sharing my linux desktop so I can transfer files work<->home.

During remote windows session I can see \\tsclient\desktop mapping to my linux desktop. That's fine, but I'm wondering if anyone else using my workplace LAN can access \\tsclient (i.e. my linux computer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tsclient shares are only visible to your remote desktop session. When another user log on the same machine she/he would see a different list of tsclient shares.

That said, as long as you have access to the files in your session, other programs in the same remote desktop session can access your files. For example if the server is infected by a virus, files on your tsclient shares could be infected too.